# Nginx config should I deny requests that are missing the accept header

Tags: http-headers

So I block requests that have a missing / empty **user agent** header because there is no reason why the **user agent** should be not present or empty since all legit browsers and bots (googlebot etc) send that header.

```
##If the user agent is missing empty or contains just a single hyphen.
if ($http_user_agent ~ "^-?$") {
return 403;
}
```

And from my research apparently the **Accept** header should always be present even if it is empty it should be sent regardless. The header should not be missing.

But before going and denying requests that don't send an **Accept** header I wanted to verify that it won't have bad effects I see modsecurity and a few others (not so sure about OWASP) say if the accept header should be present at least. (From what I can see it should be sent and allowed access as long as the header was present in the request and not missing.)

I made the following rule for Nginx have not put it into production use since I need more information about if that header should be missing or not.

```
## Prevent Missing Accept header
set $block_missing_accept_header 0;
#If Accept header present
if ($http_accept) {
set $block_missing_accept_header 1;
}
#Header was missing so deny request
if ($block_missing_accept_header = 0) {
return 403;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That rule was my idea, so here is my thinking on it.

What I observed over a very large sample of requests is that actual web browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome, Konqueror, Opera, and others) always sent the Accept header. But robots did not always do so, depending on a variety of factors such as the HTTP library, the programmer's competence, etc.

Then, robots *pretending* to be web browsers with a fake User-Agent string would sometimes be missing the Accept header.

So, the idea here was to catch out robots pretending to be web browsers and doing it poorly, by not sending the Accept header.

To implement this rule, you must *also* check that the User-Agent string starts with "Mozilla". It's not appropriate to block unless both of these conditions are met: The user agent claims to be a web browser, and the Accept header is missing.

```
if ($http_user_agent ~ ^Mozilla) {
    set $block_missing_accept_header "Mozilla";
}
if ($http_accept = false) {
    set $block_missing_accept_header "${block_missing_accept_header}NoAccept";
}
if ($block_missing_accept_header == "MozillaNoAccept") {
    return 403;
}
```

Comment: I see where you come from but the issue with that is like trying to build a whitelist of every single user agent in existence, there is just too many. For example : Google say Googlebot always sends both user agent and accept headers in all requests so you would need to do checks on Google bot requests that have one header but are missing the other, The same goes for every type of crawler / bot what is why I am avoiding the whitelist factor and asked would the accept header ever be missing in a legit request. (No legit request ever has the User Agent missing.)

Comment: The following source also shows that the accept should never be missing from any request from my understanding https://www.abyssguard.com/wiki/features/headers-check/ ModSecurity and others also have rules that say it should always be present.

Comment: Also the accept header I am not trying to make sure it has contents it could be blank / empty as long as the header was present within the request, Because that seems to be the checks that everyone else is doing, They all check that the header was in fact present and not missing. The contents of it does not seem to matter for example if I go to FaceBook and remove my user agent I get redirected if I go to PornHub the same thing happens. But this accept field seems to be the one that all the security engines don't allow to be missing but no documentation should it be mandatory header to be sent

Comment: @C0nw0nk The Accept header [is _not_ mandatory](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-5.3.2); it's just that every _browser_ uses it. You asked about my rule and I explained it. If you don't like the explanation, you can always believe whatever you want to believe.

Comment: Thanks for the link i figured it was already not mandatory since people can browse without sending that header. My question said should I block requests when it is missing that is what I am after, I just need to know if all legit requests would always contain that field even if it was blank / empty at least it was sent because I don't want to make the accept header mandatory and find search engine crawlers and legit traffic gets blocked. It is like the User agent field the contents can be spoofed and changed but it should not be missing.

Comment: @C0nw0nk Legit requests from all known browsers (and the stupid search engine crawlers that say they're Mozilla) will always have it. Legit requests from _bots_ might not have it. Its absence alone is not good enough to block a _bot_, but only when it is pretending to be a web browser and thus behaving badly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that clients with no user-agent should be blocked.

- All legitimate robots requests have a HTTP user-agent field: googlebot, bing, baidu...
- All legitimate known SEO robot requests have a HTTP user-agent: moz, majestic, semrush..
- All legitimate browser requests have a HTTP user-agent: Chome, Edge, Brave, Mozilla...
- linux commands add a user-agent by default: curl, kurly